# Is there a Performance impact when using Embedded PDBs

Tags: c#, .net

Does using embedded PDBs in .NET projects impact performance in any way?

For clarity I'm talking about `<DebugType>portable</DebugType>` vs `<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>`.

My guess is embedding the PDB impacts the size of the assembly loaded into memory so might waste a bit of memory.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/a/63791074/495455

Comment: _[The size of an Windows EXE generally has no bearing on it's presence in RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941153/size-of-exe-file-vs-available-memory)_.  It's also true for WIN32 EXEs with lots of/large resources